# Firebase iOS app finds deleted value at path even though I deleted it in Firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    ref.child(lastCallHistoryFetchPath).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let lastFetch = snapshot.value as? [String : String]{
            if let date = lastFetch["date"]{
                self.mostRecentDateTime = DateStruct.callHistoryStrToDate(dateStr: date)
                if let time = lastFetch["time"]{
                    self.mostRecentDateTime?.addTime(timeStr: time)
                }
            }
        }
        self.getCallHistory(number: myNumber, uuid: phoneNumberToUuidMappings[myNumber]!)
    })
```

Even after deleting the value at lastCallHistoryPath in my backend (via firebase console), my ios application finds the old, deleted value here.  Why is this happening and how can I prevent?  I know there is a local DB stored but I thought the remotes entry would take precedence, especially since the deletion was the most recent operation.

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your firebase structure, as text please, no images and all define what lastCallHistoryFetchPath is equal to, and also clarify what you mean by *finds the old, deleted value*. What value and how was it deleted?

Comment: What I see directly is that you use `observeSingleEvent`. You should use just `observe` to listen every time to changes. This could be the reason

Comment: @ronatory That really won't have anything to do with reading in a value that was deleted - your comment would pertain to watching for changes in the database. OP: what happens if you comment out everything in the closure and replace it with print(snapshot)? Also, do you have persistence turned on?

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your information. You are right